# Elegant way to Bind Dictionary with List

Tags: c#, winforms

Other then breaking it up, Is there a simple way to take:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

And bind it into a gridview control in winforms ?

Comment: Hope you find an answer. This sort of use case is much easier in WPF if you can switch to it.

Comment: I would write an extension method that returned what you expected.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks Bradley wish that was an option !

Comment: As your grid is expecting a list, you will need to create a list, which means you need to break it up

Comment: @Larry I looked through the mentioned and several other questions however they do not take into the account the List<s> value

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna. I realized my mistake and revoked my duplicate vote close. I am afraid the gridview control does not handle subgrids, and it is no possible a simple way. However, why not to give the ListView a try? It handles Groups pretty well. It wont take that long to write the code that populate its content from your dictionary.

Comment: A GridView is for showing tables, you have a Tree. How do you want it to look? The data fits better with a Grouped ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a GridView, but a grouped ListView gives quite good results:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;

namespace so
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        ListView lv;

        public Form1()
        {
            lv = new ListView 
                 { 
                    Parent = this, 
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
                    ShowGroups = true, 
                    View = View.Details
                 };
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            var dic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
            {
                { "group 1", new[] { "sorry", "for having voted", "close for duplicate", "too fast" }.ToList() },
                { "group 2", new[] { "this is not", "a gridview", "but the result", "looks like" }.ToList() },
                { "group 3", new[] { "what you", "are trying", "to achieve" }.ToList() },
                { "group 4", new[] { "hope", "it", "helps" }.ToList() }
            };

            lv.BeginUpdate();

            lv.Columns.Clear();
            lv.Columns.Add("Text");

            lv.Groups.Clear();
            lv.Groups.AddRange(
                dic.Keys.Select(
                    s => new ListViewGroup(s, s)).ToArray());

            lv.Items.Clear();
            lv.Items.AddRange(
                dic.SelectMany(kv => 
                    kv.Value.Select(item => 
                        new ListViewItem
                            { 
                                Text = item,
                                Group = lv.Groups[kv.Key]
                            })).ToArray());

            lv.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);

            lv.EndUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this insight.  Don't work in winforms often.  My original thought was a gridview with a dropdown column but given the usecase I think this is more appropriate.  Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

One way to show in datagrid would be to create 2 columns and for each value in list add a row:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a Datatable
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Col1");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Col2");
        //For each key pair
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> keyValuePair in dict)
        {
            List<string> list = keyValuePair.Value;
            //Add a row for the each item in list
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
                row["Col1"] = keyValuePair.Key;
                row["Col2"] = item;
                dataTable.Rows.Add(row);    
            }
        }

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell how output must look like, it might for example:

```
    private void ElegantwaytoBindDictionarywithList()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            {
                "Foo", new List<string>{"foo1","foo2"}
            },
            {
                "Bar", new List<string>{"bar1","bar2"}
            }
        };

        var source = new BindingSource {DataSource = dict};

        dataGridView1.RowsAdded += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var key = dict.Skip(args.RowIndex).First().Key;

            dataGridView1.Rows[args.RowIndex].Cells["value"].Value = string.Join(", ", dict[key]);
        };

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("value", "value");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
    }
```

[image]